# Using Python 3.3 in C++ 'python33_d.lib' not found

Tags: c++, python, visual-c++

I am trying to `#include <Python.h>` in my C++ code and when I go to compile my code I get this error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python33_d.lib'
```

I have tried to find `python33_d.lib` on my computer to include in my linker dependencies, but I cannot find it. I have been able to find `python33.lib`.

Where can I find the `python33_d.lib`, or how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`*_d.lib` is used for debug builds. Switch to a release build instead.

Comment: Now when I run it can't find the python33.dll. I add it to my Project, do I need to add a path to python33.dll to my properties?

Comment: Put that DLL somewhere the loader expects to find it, such as the current directory.

Comment: Okay so I copy pasted `Python33.dll` in my current directory and now I am getting a access violation error `Unhandled exception at 0x000000001E17D5CD (python33.dll) in PythTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.`

Comment: This is not correct solution... this is just for avoid current build error.

Answer (score 36):

Simple solution from the [python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue22411):

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
  #undef _DEBUG
  #include <python.h>
  #define _DEBUG
#else
  #include <python.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 25):

In the event that you need a debug version (as I do for work), it is possible to build the library yourself:

1. Download the source tarball from http://www.python.org/download
2. Extract the tarball (7zip will do the trick) and go into the resulting directory (should be something like Python-3.3.2).
3. From the Python directory, go to the PCBuild folder. There are two important files here: readme.txt, which contains the instructions for building Python in Windows (even if it uses the UNIX line feed style...), and pcbuild.sln, which is the Visual Studio solution that builds Python.
4. Open pcbuild.sln in Visual Studio. (I am assuming you are using Visual Studio 10; readme.txt contains specific instructions for older versions of Visual Studio.)
5. Make sure Visual Studio is set to the "debug" configuration, and then build the solution for your appropriate architecture (x64 or Win32). You may get a few failed subprojects, but not all of them are necessary to build python33_d; by my count, 8 builds failed and I got a working .lib file anyway.
6. You will find python33_d.lib and python33_d.dll in either the PCBuild folder (if building Win32) or the amd64 subfolder (if building x64).

Comment: I started down this path then after running the command `build.bat -d` I got an error saying I needed a specific version of Visual Studio (v2015) installed, which I didn't want to do. So, I went with @aquirdturtle solution, which allowed me to modify my current installation by adding the debug library. Now, I no longer get the error stated by the OP.

Comment: How do you download the source tarball??

Answer (score 12):

If you install python via the installers on python.org, you can tell the installer to include the debugging symbols and binaries such as the pythonXX_d.dll file by selecting "Customize Installation" while installing (I think it's on the second customization page). This may be the easiest solution if you're not very savvy at building the project yourself (like me). Too bad I don't see any way to do this with the anaconda distribution.

Comment: note that this option is not on the first screen you see after selecting customize (this threw me off for a bit).  You have to click the "Next" button and then you will see the option.

Comment: I do this and get the error: 
Error LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x358 App C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\python39_d.dll  
What is wrong?

Comment: No idea. I suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 10):

Open Python installer(.exe) -- Modify -- Next -- Enable checkbox `Debug Symbols and Libs`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and it takes literally 1 minute to reinstall Python including all debug symbols.

Comment: True. This should be accepted as the answer. It works without any tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swig to generate python wrappers then you can define the macro SWIG_PYTHON_INTERPRETER_NO_DEBUG. In which case it will not look for python**_d.lib

Answer (score 0):

As addition to the answer of @liorda:
It might happen that there appears conflicts with other libraries and python.
The error C1017: invalid integer constant expression may come up.

For this use @liorda's code and replace

```cpp
#define _DEBUG
```

with

```cpp
#define _DEBUG 1
```