# I cannot find python35_d.lib

Tags: c, python-3.x

I have downloaded the 3.5 version of python on my windows 7 home premium computer with version 6.1 software. I wish to use a C main program with python library extensions. I have aded the path to the include folder and the library folder to the dev studio c-compiler. I am testing with the supplied test program that prints out the time but I get a compile error. While it can find Python.h, it can't find python35_d.lib. I can't either. Is it missing from the download or is this another name for a one of the libraries in the download? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python 3.3 in C++ 'python33\_d.lib' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028576/using-python-3-3-in-c-python33-d-lib-not-found)

Answer (score 13):

Maybe a little too late, but I found a work around for the missing 'python3x_d.lib' : When installing the python with pythoninstaller.exe, choose the advanced setup options in the first command window of the installation wizard, there choose the option "download debug binaries", then the file python3x_d.lib is automatically installed. 
I faced this error when trying to build opencv with python bindings

Comment: note that this option is not on the first screen you see after selecting customize (this threw me off for a bit). You have to click the "Next" button and then you will see the option.