# Embed Python in C++ VS2015

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to embed python code in C++ console application vs2015. I followed the tutorial https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html, the very first example, 5.1 Very High Level Embedding.
But when I debug, it shows an error : Impossible to start the program because the python34_d.dll is missed. I think it should be a problem of configuration, but I don't really know how to resolve.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Make sure the DLL is in a directory that's in the PATH (environment variable), or else in the executable's directory. To change the default for PATH, command `sysdm.cpl`, choose tab Advanced, button Environment Variables, create or modify a user PATH default in upper part of that dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually this dll doesn't even exist. There is python34.dll, but not python34_d.dll, where d stands for debug. I wander if I should compile something to get python34_d.dll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python 3.3 in C++ 'python33\_d.lib' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028576/using-python-3-3-in-c-python33-d-lib-not-found)

Comment: I've tried both x64 and win32, none of them generate .dll file actually...

Answer (score 0):

Build it in Release mode, worked for me. python34_d.dll tends to be  debug