# Why isn't CPython 3.4.3 able to import '_socket' module?

Tags: python, c++, sockets, python-import, cpython

I have a C++ program, which has an embedded python 3.4.3+. I am attempting to run a script which uses a module named `requests`, this module depends on `socket`, but the embedded interpreter in unable to import `_socket`

Python Version and Callstack

```
3.4.3+ (3.4:f4cd9ac378d7+, Feb 16 2016, 21:24:03) [MSC v.1800 32 bit (Intel)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<project path>\client_example.py", line 30, in <module>
    import requests
  File "F:\Python 3.4.3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "F:\Python 3.4.3\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "F:\Python 3.4.3\Lib\cgi.py", line 39, in <module>
    from email.parser import FeedParser
  File "F:\Python 3.4.3\Lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "F:\Python 3.4.3\Lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "F:\Python 3.4.3\Lib\email\message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "F:\Python 3.4.3\Lib\email\utils.py", line 29, in <module>
import socket
  File "F:\Python 3.4.3\Lib\socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: No module named '_socket'
```

I also know that `_socket.pyd` is located in DLLs in the python install location, however I don't know if it should also be in another location.

How can I make my program's embedded interpreter find the `_socket` module?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the python terminal and load the socket library? (i.e. "import socket")
I see you are using MSVC, meaning you are using windows. To open the python terminal open a command prompt and just type python and press enter. You are now in the python terminal.

If that does not work, then there is a problem with the python installation.

Another thing, if you installed python using a proper python installer well the problem will most probably not be due to a bad install.

Best regards.

Comment: Yes I have run the python terminal and successfully imported both socket and _socket. The problem seems only to lye within the embedded interpreter.

Comment: Hmm, I think I had a similar problem a few months back. Do you have the environment variables for python created? (PYTHONHOME, PYTHONPATH). I think that fixed it for me, by inserting into the PYTHONPATH variable the direction to the Lib folder of python. In my case, I could not load numpy (a site package) and by using the PYTHONPATH I managed to load it!

Comment: I currently am unable to check and try, however I will try tomorrow and report back!

Answer (score 0):

try adding the path to the module to python:

```
sys.path.append(path/to/module)
```

this should allow you to import the module.

Comment: I'll try this later today when home.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while debugging my c++ application in ***VS 2019***.

Because Python is missing the debug compiled files: ***_d***.dll **_d**.pyd ***d_**.lib

Solution:

1. download the source code and build your debug version
   [Debug Version Build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17659306/12074069)
2. copy from .\PCbuild\amd64 to your python directory

   - *._d.dll   ==> .\%PYTHONHOME%\
   - *._d.pyd   ==> .\%PYTHONHOME%\DLLs
   - *._d.pdb   ==> .\%PYTHONHOME%\DLLs
   - *._d.lib   ==> .\%PYTHONHOME%\libs
3. Set environment variables `%PYTHONHOME%` and `%PYTHONPATH%`
4. Add the path to sys.path

   ```
   PyObject* sys_path = PySys_GetObject("path");
   retVal = PyList_Append(sys_path, PyUnicode_FromString("C:\\Python38_64\\DLLs"));
   ```
5. try debugging again ;-)